# User Input: Yes or no in C

Tags: c, if-statement, input

I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with this. It compiles fine, but no matter what I put in, be it yes or no, it skips over the "let's begin" line and goes straight to the end.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char response[5];
    printf("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
    printf("Would you like to go on an adventure?\n Enter Yes or No:");
    scanf("%s", response);
    if (response == "yes"){
        printf("Let's begin!");
    }
    else (response == "no");{
        printf("See you later then!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Does the scan need to be moved, or did I just screw it up somehow?

Comment: The `==` does not compare arrays. If use on arrays it compares the addresses of the two array's 1st element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
if (response == "yes"){
```

to

```
if(!strcmp(response, "yes") {
```

For the "no" check, write `else if(!strcmp(response, "no") {` if you want to explicitly check for "no".

Comment: And the OP should remove the `(response == "no")` in the else.

Comment: Thanks for catching that, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Hey, that fixed it! Thanks a ton; I had no clue that I couldn't use == for chars.

Comment: @hego64 you can use `==` for characters. But you were trying to compare two different addresses. `response` is the address of the response. `"yes"` is the address of the string `"yes"` in memory. So `response == "yes"` compares memory addresses of two different arrays of characters.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing array of chars. So `==` will not work. 
Either implement equals function for 2 array of chars or use string class.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (strcmp(response, "yes")==0){
    printf("Let's begin!");
}
else {
    printf("See you later then!");
}
```

You cannot compare two char arrays. 0 is returned from strcmp when the strings are the same. Make sure to include .

Answer (score 0):

in c programming you can't directly compare array of characters by using assignment operator  instead you can use [strcmp](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp) to check both the string are equal or not